# split string in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, split

In my table, I have Experience field like

**Experience**

- 0to0Years
- 2to0Years
- 7to12Years

Here I want to split into

- Yearfrom - 0
- Yearto- 0

How to split strings here. I search so many articles. I can't find the correct solution. Is there any way to do here?

Comment: what to save it in DB or just disply?

Comment: i want to use select statement now. so it is just display means ok.then i execute another table.

Comment: ok fine, wait for a while.

Comment: you will have to use substring function , i am also working on it for this query.

Comment: ok. I use substring(exp,start,end)

Comment: see how its used over here substring with combination of charindex function http://forums.asp.net/t/1719649.aspx/1

Comment: really interesting and challenging mind stuff..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working solution

```
declare @yearfrom varchar(2),@yearto varchar(2)

select @yearfrom=substring('0to0Years',0,patindex('%to%','0to0Years')),
 @yearto=substring('0to0Years',patindex('%to%','0to0Years')+2,patindex('%Years%','0to0Years')-patindex('%to%','0to0Years')-2)
```

SqlFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12483

For working on your column replace '0to0Years' with column name

```
    declare @yearfrom varchar(2),@yearto varchar(2)

        select @yearfrom=substring(col_name,0,patindex('%to%',col_name)),
         @yearto=substring(,patindex('%to%',col_name)+2,patindex('%Years%',col_name)-patindex('%to%',col_name)-2)
from table_name where <condition>
```

Comment: This one is good. But i have some problem when i use select insert query like, select top(5)'insert jobs()values('+
   substring(Experience,0,patindex('%to%',Experience))*365*24*60*60 ,
   substring(Experience,patindex('%to%',Experience)+2,patindex('%Years%',Experience)-patindex('%to%',Experience)-2)+')'
from requirementsdetailsfororganization                      and getting error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'insert jobs()values(' to data type int."

Answer (score 0):

Try this using  [Parsename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188006.aspx) function

```
Select  parsename(replace(Experience,'to','.'),2) ,
        substring(parsename(replace(Experience,'to','.'),1),0,
        charindex('Y',parsename(replace(Experience,'to','.'),1))) 
from YourTable
```

Demo in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f408d/2)

Comment: did u find one issue there? when execute this query, result is for oto12years. so it will give 0  12y. If i remove that place means problem in 0to0years. "0" is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following Steps...

```
                            --Create Table :
                            Create Table #Table
                            (
                            Name Varchar(50),
                            Experience Varchar(20)
                            )
                            Go

                            -- Insert Values :
                            Insert into #Table Values('Tom','0to0Years')
                            Insert into #Table Values('Victor','0to1Years')
                            Insert into #Table Values('Mark','11to12Years')
                            Go

                            --View Data
                            Select  * from #Table

                            --Using CharIndex  and Substring :
                            Select Name,
                            Substring(Experience,1,CharIndex('to',Experience)-1) as Yearfrom,
                            Substring(Experience,(CharIndex('to',Experience)+2),Len(Replace(Experience,'Years','')) - (CharIndex('to',Experience)+1)) as YearTo
                            from #Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 'YearFrom - '+substring(Data, 0, PatIndex('%[to]%', Data)) YearFrom, 
    'YearTo - '+replace(stuff(Data, 1, PatIndex('%[to]%', Data)+1, ''), 'Years', '') YearTo
from
(
    Select '0to0Years' Data union
    Select '2to0Years' Data union
    Select '756to12Years' Data
)x
```